# bulk loader appcfg.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I am trying to dowload data using

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://cayotkanawa.appspot.com/_ah/
remote_api --filename=datasave.csv
```

But I get this. What I should do to get data?

```
C:\Users\Honjo>appcfg.py download_data --url=http://cayotkanawa.appspot.com/_ah/
remote_api --filename=datasave.csv
Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>

Action must be one of:
  backends: Perform a backend action.
  backends configure: Reconfigure a backend without stopping it.
  backends delete: Delete a backend.
  backends list: List all backends configured for the app.
  backends rollback: Roll back an update of a backend.
  backends start: Start a backend.
  backends stop: Stop a backend.
  backends update: Update one or more backends.
  create_bulkloader_config: Create a bulkloader.yaml from a running application.

  cron_info: Display information about cron jobs.
  download_app: Download a previously-uploaded app.
  download_data: Download entities from datastore.
  help: Print help for a specific action.
  request_logs: Write request logs in Apache common log format.
  resource_limits_info: Get the resource limits.
  rollback: Rollback an in-progress update.
  set_default_version: Set the default (serving) version.
  update: Create or update an app version.
  update_cron: Update application cron definitions.
  update_dos: Update application dos definitions.
  update_indexes: Update application indexes.
  update_queues: Update application task queue definitions.
  upload_data: Upload data records to datastore.
  vacuum_indexes: Delete unused indexes from application.
Use 'help <action>' for a detailed description.

Options:
  -h, --help            Show the help message and exit.
  -q, --quiet           Print errors only.
  -v, --verbose         Print info level logs.
  --noisy               Print all logs.
  -s SERVER, --server=SERVER
                        The App Engine server.
  --insecure            Use HTTP when communicating with the server.
  -e EMAIL, --email=EMAIL
                        The username to use. Will prompt if omitted.
  -H HOST, --host=HOST  Overrides the Host header sent with all RPCs.
  --no_cookies          Do not save authentication cookies to local disk.
  --skip_sdk_update_check
                        Do not check for SDK updates.
  --passin              Read the login password from stdin.
  -A APP_ID, --application=APP_ID
                        Set the application, overriding the application value
                        from app.yaml file.
  -V VERSION, --version=VERSION
                        Set the (major) version, overriding the version value
                        from app.yaml file.
  -r RUNTIME, --runtime=RUNTIME
                        Override runtime from app.yaml file.
  -R, --allow_any_runtime
                        Do not validate the runtime in app.yaml
  --oauth2              Use OAuth2 instead of password auth.
  --oauth2_refresh_token=OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN
                        An existing OAuth2 refresh token to use. Will not
                        attempt interactive OAuth approval.
  --noauth_local_webserver
                        Do not run a local web server to handle redirects
                        during OAuth authorization.
  -f, --force           Force deletion without being prompted.
  --has_header          Whether the first line of the input file should be
                        skipped
  --loader_opts=LOADER_OPTS
                        A string to pass to the Loader.initialize method.
  --url=URL             The location of the remote_api endpoint.
  --batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
                        Number of records to post in each request.
  --bandwidth_limit=BANDWIDTH_LIMIT
                        The maximum bytes/second bandwidth for transfers.
  --rps_limit=RPS_LIMIT
                        The maximum records/second for transfers.
  --http_limit=HTTP_LIMIT
                        The maximum requests/second for transfers.
  --db_filename=DB_FILENAME
                        Name of the progress database file.
  --auth_domain=AUTH_DOMAIN
                        The name of the authorization domain to use.
  --log_file=LOG_FILE   File to write bulkloader logs.  If not supplied then a
                        new log file will be created, named: bulkloader-log-
                        TIMESTAMP.
  --dry_run             Do not execute any remote_api calls
  --namespace=NAMESPACE
                        Namespace to use when accessing datastore.
  --num_threads=NUM_THREADS
                        Number of threads to transfer records with.
  --filename=FILENAME   The name of the file where output data is to be
                        written. (Required)
  --kind=KIND           The kind of the entities to retrieve.
  --exporter_opts=EXPORTER_OPTS
                        A string to pass to the Exporter.initialize method.
  --result_db_filename=RESULT_DB_FILENAME
                        Database to write entities to for download.
  --config_file=CONFIG_FILE
                        Name of the configuration file.
  --num_runs=NUM_RUNS   Number of runs of each cron job to displayDefault is 5
  --no_precompilation   Disable automatic Python precompilation.
  --backends            Update backends when performing appcfg update.
  -n NUM_DAYS, --num_days=NUM_DAYS
                        Number of days worth of log data to get. The cut-off
                        point is midnight US/Pacific. Use 0 to get all
                        available logs. Default is 1, unless --append is also
                        given; then the default is 0.
  -a, --append          Append to existing file.
  --severity=SEVERITY   Severity of app-level log messages to get. The range
                        is 0 (DEBUG) through 4 (CRITICAL). If omitted, only
                        request logs are returned.
  --vhost=VHOST         The virtual host of log messages to get. If omitted,
                        all log messages are returned.
  --include_vhost       Include virtual host in log messages.
  --include_all         Include everything in log messages.
  --end_date=END_DATE   End date (as YYYY-MM-DD) of period for log data.
                        Defaults to today.

C:\Users\Honjo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so strange put the following command worked

```
python "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" download_data --url=http://cayotkanawa.appspot.com/_ah/
remote_api --filename=datasave.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the reason, but from your output: `Usage: appcfg.py [options] <action>`
Your command has the action before the options.
If it doesn't work - try `appcpg.py help download_data` to get a better description of how to use the `download_data` action.

Comment: I got the code from here
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Setting_Up_remote_api

Comment: Is it possible that you are using a different version of app engine than the one describing the command and that the usage has changed? (though I am just speculating here)

Comment: thanks for reply. I just stated using google app engine so that the version I download is the most updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your commandline looks correct.  Is it just StackOverflow displaying your command on two lines, or did you actually type it in on two lines?  It should be one line.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, setting the app id (s~ is a prefix for HR datastore apps) while creating the bulkloader config file helped:

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config -A s~foo-app --url=https://foo-app.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=bulkloader.yaml

appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --url=http://foo-app.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=accounts.csv --kind=Account --namespace='lol'
```